# div inside td - vertical-align: middle. not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know that this question has many answers, BUT I couldn't find a good answer that fix my problem.

So, I have a div inside a td. and all I want is to the div will set into the middle of the td, yes that simple!

For the convenience I'm adding this image:

[image]

```css
.tdClass{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
    
.divClass{
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
        first field:
      </td>
      <td>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
        <div class="divClass">
        VERTICAL CENTER???
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You don't have any element with a class of `tdClass`.

Comment: you want vertical align right, not horizontal align ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
}
.tdClass{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.divClass{
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
textarea{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td>
    first field:
  </td>
  <td>
    <textarea rows="4"></textarea>
    <div class="divClass">
        VERTICAL CENTER???
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: YES! it was the textarea that made the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

use `display: flex` to the larger table-data field.

Here is the updated code.

**HTML and CSS**

```css
.tdClass{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.divClass{
  display:inline;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.text-section{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.divClass{
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td>
    first field:
  </td>
  <td class="text-section">
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <div class="divClass">
    VERTICAL CENTER???
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2cvaw6k5/6/)

Comment: Almost.. this field set up great. but all other items in the table are disrupted.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, table tag is vertical center by default. Secondly, you have written .tdClass and never used it in any place.

https://jsfiddle.net/wazmgz3g/1/

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td>
    first field:
  </td>
  <td>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <div class="divClass" width='100%'>
    <center>VERTICAL CENTER???</center>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please visit this JS fiddle and check if that is what you expect. If so copy it.

Thank you.